# How can I commit specific directory to a different than a working branch on git?

Tags: git, github

I have a simple static website, based on [HTML 5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) and the whole thing is in a github repository. The project structure is something like this

```
build
css    
img
js
publish    # this directory isn't in source control!

...

index.html & other files
```

Basically what I do is run a build script ([from HTML 5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/Build-script/)) that **compiles all the HTML/CSS/JS into the `publish` directory, which isn't in the git repository**.

Now what I want to do, is make use of [GitHub pages](http://pages.github.com/) and be able to use the `publish` directory output as a GitHub page.

The way GitHub pages work, is that you create a clean separate branch named `gh-pages`, which will contain the final content. **What I want to do, is to be able to on demand commit the current `publish` directory into the `gh-pages` branch**, but I also want to keep it in the main `.gitignore` file so it won't get pushed into the source repository.

I want to do this to kinda preview the current state of the project.

**in short:** *I need to commit one directory to a separate branch, so it's root will be the same as contents of that one directory. `publish/css` will become just `css` on the `gh-pages` branch*

Comment: See [my related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29616287/946850) and a [writeup](http://krlmlr.github.io/git-subbranch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `.gitignore` is versioned as well, just don't put the `publish/` directory in the `gh-pages` branch's `.gitignore` file. Then, you can just do something like this:

```
ORIG_HEAD="$(git name-rev --name-only HEAD)" git checkout gh-pages && mv publish/* . && git commit -am "automatic update" && git checkout "$ORIG_HEAD"
```

It does get tricky since you're wanting to do things in the root directory rather than a subdirectory. Another option would be to simply maintain a separate clone of the same repository in a different directory, that is always on the `gh-pages` branch. You could have your script just write the files to there instead of to `publish/` and then just commit in that clone.

Comment: I guess I could make the `publish/` itself as a repository and directly commit and push from there, that would make things much simpler.

Comment: You could indeed. I don't think there's anything that would be problematic in having a repository be a submodule of itself, as long as they're not on the same branch.