# How to build docs in one branch and automatically copy build/html into the gh-pages branch

Tags: git, github, python-sphinx

Github stores project websites in in a seperate branch (gh-pages) of the project repository. 
We have in master a sphinx package that builds our docs and want to automatically commit the generated docs to the gh-pages branch.

Sphinx config and the source cannot be in the gh-pages branch themselves because that branch contains only html.If the master didnt' version the html it self, this would be see(use .git ignore as shown here [How can I commit specific directory to a different than a working branch on git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212290/how-can-i-commit-specific-directory-to-a-different-than-a-working-branch-on-git)). What happens if it is version.

I want to type make publish and have it build the docs ( we have this as a make target already) and then apply those changes to the gh-pages branch (forcibly in fact).

The problem is that gh-pages is effectively  the contents of  doc/build/html , so a standard merge would seem not to work.

stashing the changes,changing branches, and applying  results in conflicts  and there appears to be no way to specify a merge strategy of --ours.

Sub-tree merging and such techniques appear to be intended for merging external repositories, not things in the same repo.

Comment: See [my related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29616287/946850) and a [writeup](http://krlmlr.github.io/git-subbranch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a branch which is empty and where you can only commit your html's.
just follow the github pages instructions for "Project Pages" from [here](http://pages.github.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I found [these steps](https://gist.github.com/brantfaircloth/791759) very useful for publishing to a different branch like `gh-pages`. There are some other scripts you can google, but this one seemed more clearly written.

Generally the steps are:
- add your current `outdir` to `.gitignore`
- clone whole repo to `outdir` to initiate .git there, clean it and make a `gh-pages` branch
- make a build that you push from outdir.

You can follow the code that uses two separate folders for `master` and `gh-pages` [here](https://idie.ru/posts/sphinx-github-pages/), the comments are in Russian, but commands are rather self-explanatory.

Comment: Hi, here link is down. Thanks