# How to properly commit in repository with Github Pages branch

Tags: git, github, github-pages

i've got a question

Situation based on [gh-pages](https://pages.github.com/)

My project uses preprocessors and another difficult staff, so, my project stucture looks as follows:

**master branch**

```
./-|
   /src
   /node_modules
   /public-|
       /js
       /css
       /etc
       index.html           
   /etc
   package.json 
   etc
```

all code sources in **src** folder, compiled - into **public** folder.
**public** folder also in .gitignore
I would like to commit all files in my public folder into gh-pages branch. Is it possible? If yes, how to do this? This is a structure of my **gh-pages** branch

**gh-pages branch**

```
 ./-|
    /js
    /css
    /assets
    index.html
```

I think it will be great to run grunt/gulp tasks and commit result into another branch.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7212290/946850

Comment: Hey @Martijn Pieters, this question is not a duplicate of another, and my answer is as tailored as it gets. Please consider undeleting it.

Answer (score 4):

I have a pair of scripts that do exactly this. In my situation, doc sources are in `.` (relative to where the scripts are run, of course), generated documentation is in `_build/html`, and I issue the commands

```
touch _build/html/.nojekyll    # disable GitHub's Jekyll page generator
./commit-to-gh-pages.sh _build/html
```

where `commit-to-gh-pages.sh` is

```
#! /bin/sh

# Commit the generated HTML pages to the branch gh-pages.
# Will not push them to GitHub.

set -e -v

treehash=$(./hash-tree.py "${1:-_build/html}")
parent=$(git rev-parse gh-pages)

msg="Regenerated docs for $(git rev-parse HEAD)"
commithash=$(echo "$msg" | git commit-tree $treehash -p $parent)
echo "Updating gh-pages to $commithash"
git update-ref refs/heads/gh-pages "$commithash"
```

This writes the directory `_build/html` to the Git index, makes a commit object that has exactly this directory tree as its contents, and writes the commit object to the `gh-pages` branch with the previous state of that branch as the parent.

The tricky part is the `hash-tree.py` script, which extends the `git hash-object` command to directory trees. I won't copy-paste it, but you can get it [here](https://github.com/NLeSC/xtas/blob/master/doc/hash-tree.py). (If anyone knows a more elegant way to do this, please tell me.)

Comment: i need a time to understand this script, some of git commands i see in first

Comment: @Viachaslau Nor did I know them before I started writing this :) These commands are part of the "plumbing", http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain

Comment: This is fascinating! Not so much for human use, but probably ideal in a scripted environment.

Answer (score 3):

I have had excellent experience with cloning the repo *into a subdirectory of itself* and checking out a different branch: For your case something like

```
# add public to .gitignore
git clone . public
cd public
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
git reset --hard
git commit --allow-empty "initial"
```

gets you started. See http://krlmlr.github.io/git-subbranch for a writeup.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `git subtree` if you have git version > 1.7.11. I can barely manage to understand the details myself yet, so I won't try to explain it, but there is a tutorial at [Hugo website builder](http://gohugo.io/tutorials/github_pages_blog/). The relevant part starts at the heading *configure git workflow*.